# Calling Web APIs from VB.NET Desktop application

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application, chilkat

Following Nordigen's Quickstart details here https://nordigen.com/en/account_information_documenation/integration/quickstart_guide/
where my VB.NET desktop calls the Nordigen API, to let my customers choose their account then login so I can retrieve transaction details. My chosen component for the various web requests is **Chilkat** using *Chilkat.Rest* objects.

Going well until Step 4.2. I open a browser window with the url provided to me from the API, go through the end-user authentication process but once that is complete I am struggling to return 'control' to my VB.NET application. My redirect uri is http://localhost but I simply get "localhost refused to connect". There's obviously something missing but I'm unsure what. Managed this before with the HMRC MTD API for oAuth where you provide a port on ListenPort and all magically works. No oAuth needed this time however.

Any help/pointers gratefully received

Comment: Is your app listening on localhost as well? Or is it just a windows forms app?
How do you open The login page from your app?

Comment: Thanks for your time - it's just a Windows form app, written in VB.NET. The login page is opened via a simple call to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start with the required url.

Comment: since your browser tries to open http://localhost, and there is nothing listening there, (your windows forms app is not running a http server) then I would not expect it to connect. (if it does, it does so to something else) One way is to actually run a webserver in your application, But I think a better approach would be to use a external server that you trust and can be used to exchange any tokens.